# @media screen css property doesn't respond?

Tags: html, css, mobile, dreamweaver

My @media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) doesn't seem to respond. I also put the

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css"/>
```

and the

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

in my Index.html.

I only have this in my mobile.css:

```css
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 640px)
 {
 #navbar {
     height: 11%;   
     }
 }
```

What do I miss? I work btw in dreamweaver cs4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max-device-width` and/or `min-device-width` needs an actual device to take effect, to debug your code on desktop you need to use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

  #navbar {
    height: 11%;    
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you also know how to make images smaller when I use media screen and width? The images are in my HTML and I don't know exactly how to size them..only giving the width to the div won't work.

Comment: Can you post the HTML structure for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Device Emulator in Chrome Browser](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=de#enable-emulation-panel),

if you develop for mobile devices, but don't have one to test on, 
It provides presets of existing devices (iPhone, HTC, Google...) and allows to edit resolution, orientation etc.

Answer (score 0):

i'm think this...

```
 #navbar {
     height: 11%;   
     max-height:11%;
     }
```

so it never going to revase the max height